# Name for a function obtained by fixing one variable and letting the other vary

Tags: reference-request, terminology

If $f:A\times B\to C$ is a function, then we sometimes consider functions of the form $f(a,\cdot)$ (where $a\in A$) or $f(\cdot,b)$ (where $b\in B$) that are obtained by fixing one variable and letting the other vary. For instance, in linear algebra, the definition of a bilinear map involves consideration of these kinds of functions.

**Question:** is there a name for functions of these form? Ideally, I would like to see a reference.

Comment: I might call it a ‘slice’ but I can’t remember if I’ve seen that in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDX’s answer and mr_e_man’s subequent comment pointed me towards the term *partial application*, which is used in computer science. The functions $f(a,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot,b)$ as defined above are partial applications of $f$. More generally, if $f$ is a function of $n$ variables, then a partial application of $f$ is a map obtained by fixing $m$ arguments of $f$ (where $1\le m<n)$.

As far as I can tell, the term *partial function* refers to a different concept: a partial function from $X$ to $Y$ is a binary relation $f$ which associates to each member of $X$, *at most one* value of $Y$ – thus, such an $f$ might not be defined for every member of $X$.

However, the term *partial application* has not seemed to have entered mainstream mathematical usage, and I am quite happy to instead use FShrike’s suggestion of calling it a “slice”.

Answer (score -2):

It is called a **partial function**. It is defined as function defined on a subset of the whole intial set.

For instance here, instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$ you have $ \{a\} \times \mathbb{R} $.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application